# Apache Redirect with keeping URL in the addressbar. (no images loading)

Tags: apache-http-server, redirection

I need some help with my apache configuration. I want a redirect from the domain example.com/test/ to subdomain.example.com/, with keeping the URL in the adressbar.

So when I type my www.example.com/test/ I want to see the content of http://subdomain.example.com with the URL example.com/test/ in the addressbar.

This is my configuration.

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass /test/ http://subdomain.example.com/
ProxyHTMLURLMap http://subdomain.example.com/ /test

<Location /test/>
ProxyPassReverse /
ProxyHTMLEnable On
ProxyHTMLURLMap / /test/
RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
</Location>
```

Everything works fine except of the images and some fonts, etc. There are locate at subdomain.example.com/Images/, subdomain.example.com/fonts/ and subdomain.example.com/Content/.

I tried it with PorxyPassMatch

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.png)$" "http://driveandlife.mercedes-benz.de/$1"
ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.jpeg)$" "http://driveandlife.mercedes-benz.de/$1"
ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.jpg)$" "http://driveandlife.mercedes-benz.de/$1"
ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.img)$" "http://driveandlife.mercedes-benz.de/$1"
```

and

```
ProxyPass /fonts/ http://subdomain.example.com/fonts/
ProxyPass /Images/ http://subdomain.example.com/Images/
ProxyPass /Content/ http://subdomain.example.com/Content/
```

**Problem:**

**ProxyPassMatch**
With ProxyPassMatch I have following problem every picture on the site example.com gets a redirect to subdomain.example.com.

**ProxyPass:**
Seems to work, but the problem is, I have also content on example.com/Content/. So when I visit this site I get a redirect to subdomain.example.com/test :(.

I any suggestion?

Comment: I am sorry dude, but i dont think that this is possible. If the root directory for subdomain.example.com  is in that server just do "Alias /test /path/to/the/root/directory/of/subdomain.example.com"

Comment: Unfortunately the domain "subdomain.example.com" is on a diffrent server.